# Select multiple values in LIKE Operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, like, operator

I have a SQL query given below, I want to select multiple value using `like` operator.

Is my Query correct?

```
SELECT top 1 employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt 
FROM       employee
INNER JOIN employee_mdata_history 
ON         employee.ident=employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
WHERE      employee_id like 'emp1%' , 'emp3%' 
ORDER BY   rx_dt desc
```

If not, can anyone correct me?

My table has large amount of data starting with `'emp1'` and `'emp3'`. 
Can I filter the result by top 3 "emp1" and top 2 "emp3" based on `rx_dt`?

Comment: Sometimes, a condition like `WHERE LEFT(employee_id, 4) IN ('emp1', 'emp3')` can do the trick.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Alternatively you can try the following method:

```
SELECT
  x.*
FROM
  (
    VALUES
      ('emp1%', 3),
      ('emp3%', 2)
  ) AS v (pattern, row_count)
  CROSS APPLY
  (  -- your query
    SELECT top (v.row_count)
               employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt 
    FROM       employee
    INNER JOIN employee_mdata_history
    ON         employee.ident=employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
    WHERE      employee_id like v.pattern
    ORDER BY   rx_dt desc
  ) AS x
;
```

The `VALUES` row constructor represents your pattern list as a table, additionally supplying each pattern with the number of rows to retrieve for that pattern. The CROSS APPLY operator applies your query to every row of the pattern list, i.e. to every pattern, limiting the number of rows for each pattern to the corresponding value from the pattern list.

As a side note, please let me take this opportunity to suggest that you always qualify your columns with the table alias in a query that is reading from two or more tables. That makes your query easier to read/understand. You can always use short aliases to avoid repeating potentially long table names. For instance:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  e.employee_id,
  h.employee_ident,
  ...
FROM
  dbo.employee AS e
  INNER JOIN dbo.employee_mdata_history AS h
    ON e.ident = h.employee_ident
WHERE
  e.employee_id LIKE ...
ORDER BY
  ...
```

Answer (score 14):

You should use an OR/AND condition:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
           employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt 
FROM       employee
INNER JOIN employee_mdata_history 
ON         employee.ident = employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
WHERE      employee_id like 'emp1%' 
OR         employee_id like 'emp3%' 
ORDER BY   rx_dt desc;
```

Have a look at [OR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql) on MS-Docs.

I've set up an example:

> ```
> create table employees(employee_id varchar(10), employee_name varchar(100));
>
> insert into employees values
> ('emp10', 'Bryan Nelson'),
> ('emp12', 'Rosalyn Sanders'),
> ('emp13', 'Rose Tudler'),
> ('emp20', 'Julio Gomez'),
> ('emp30', 'Ian McGregor'),
> ('emp40', 'Anne Hatt');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT employee_id, employee_name
> FROM   employees
> WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp1%'
> OR     employee_id LIKE 'emp3%';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> employee_id | employee_name  
> :---------- | :--------------
> emp10       | Bryan Nelson   
> emp12       | Rosalyn Sanders
> emp13       | Rose Tudler    
> emp30       | Ian McGregor
> ```

Keep in mind that you're using TOP 1, you'll get one row maximum, no matter how many conditions you use.

> ```
> SELECT TOP 1 employee_id, employee_name
> FROM   employees
> WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp1%'
> OR     employee_id LIKE 'emp3%';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> employee_id | employee_name
> :---------- | :------------
> emp10       | Bryan Nelson
> ```

If you need the TOP (X) rows `WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp1%'` plus TOP (X) rows `WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp3%'` you can use two select statements joined with UNION ALL.

> ```
> SELECT TOP 3 employee_id, employee_name
> FROM   employees
> WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp1%'
> UNION ALL
> SELECT TOP 1 employee_id, employee_name
> FROM   employees
> WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp3%'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> employee_id | employee_name  
> :---------- | :--------------
> emp10       | Bryan Nelson   
> emp12       | Rosalyn Sanders
> emp13       | Rose Tudler    
> emp30       | Ian McGregor
> ```

In addition I'll add a pattern search, but this solution returns all records that matches the pattern: LIKE 'emp[13]%'

> ```
> SELECT employee_id, employee_name
> FROM   employees
> WHERE  employee_id LIKE 'emp[13]%'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> employee_id | employee_name  
> :---------- | :--------------
> emp10       | Bryan Nelson   
> emp12       | Rosalyn Sanders
> emp13       | Rose Tudler    
> emp30       | Ian McGregor
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=55b402c997c1b833b88e51c71731ab99)*

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want 1 row `where employee_id like 'emp1%'` and another `where employee_id like 'emp3%'`. One way to achieve this is to use a `union`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
  ( SELECT top 1 employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt 
    FROM       employee
    JOIN employee_mdata_history 
        ON employee.ident=employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
    WHERE employee_id like 'emp1%'
    ORDER BY rx_dt desc
  ) AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*
FROM
  (  SELECT top 1 employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt 
    FROM       employee
    JOIN employee_mdata_history 
        ON employee.ident=employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
    WHERE employee_id like 'emp3%'
    ORDER BY rx_dt desc
  ) AS t2 ;
```

Since the legs in the union is guaranteed to be disjoint a `UNION ALL` can be used, and that might be a performance advantage compared to using just a `UNION`.

I believe SQL-server 2008 supports window functions like row_number(), so you can use something like:

```
SELECT employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt
FROM (
    SELECT employee_id, employee_ident, utc_dt, rx_dt
      , row_number() over (partition by substring(employee_id,1,4)
                           order by rx_dt desc) as rn 
    FROM employee
    JOIN employee_mdata_history 
        ON employee.ident = employee_mdata_history.employee_ident 
    WHERE employee_id like 'emp1%' 
       OR employee_id like 'emp3%'
) as T 
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY rx_dt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good argument. In case you need all the words of the string to be present in a field of a table, you can use the select that you find below. The query uses the PATINDEX statement which as you know works only if the words in the string are in the same order as the search field. In fact, the two segments of the PATINDEX are first sorted and then aggregated. The precondition is the existence of a table function (splitstring_ex) which returns a list of records ... hence a trivial Split.

```
select 
PATINDEX(
    (
        select '%'+STRING_AGG(z.myvalue,'%')+'%' 
        from (
                select top 100
                    [name] as myvalue
                from 
                    dbo.splitstring_ex('JKK ABC ZGT', ' ') 
                order by
                    [name]
            ) as z
    )
    ,(
        select STRING_AGG(z.myvalue,' ')
        from (
                select top 100
                    [name] as myvalue
                from 
                    dbo.splitstring_ex('AAK JKK ZGT ABC MKI', ' ') 
                order by
                    [name]
            ) as z
    )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You are using `TOP(1)` and `order by` clause. So you will get only the first top record ordered by the clause.